# How to import large dataset in r splitting and filtering by 3 different criteria when found

Tags: r

I'm dealing with a couple of txt files with climatological data with 3 parameters that differentiate each chunk of data (Parameter measured, station of measurement, and year), each file has more than a million lines, In the past I mannualy selected each parameter one a time, for a station and year and read it into r using read.fwd; but with this size files that is absurd and inefficient. Is there any way to automate this process, taking into account that the file has a "FF" as indicator every time a new parameter for a station and a given year starts and knowing that i want to generate separate files or datasets that have to be named according to the station, year and parameter to be able to use it thereafter?

[File to read Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LXbA.jpg)

Circled in red is the FF, I guess intended to mark the start of a new set of records.
Circled in Black is the name of the parameter measured (there are in total 8 different parameter classes)
Circled in blue is the year of meassurement.
Circled in green is the number or identifier of the station of measurement.

In the past, i read just what i need it with read.fwf, given the fixed with in the data, but that separation is not applied in the head of each table.

```
PRUEBA3 <- read.fwf("SanIgnacio_Pmax24h.txt", header = FALSE, widths = c(5,4,4,6,2,7,2,7,2,7,2,7,2,7,2,7,2,7,2,7,2,7,2,7,2,7,2,10,2),skip=1)
```

**Thanks, and every help will be appreciated**

Comment: Have you considered using `stringr`?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a function that loops through the txt files. (The output that you linked to was produced by a database; I assume you don't have access to it).

Here is how the function could look like using the fast fread from data.table and a foreach loop (you can make the loop parallel by registering a parallel backend and change %do% into %dopar%):

```
library(data.table)
library(foreach)

myfiles = dir(pattern = ".txt$")

res = foreach(i = 1:myfiles) %dopar% {

  x = fread(myfiles[i], na.strings = c("", " "))

  # get row indices for start and end dates
  # the "V" variables are column indices, I assume these don't change per file
  start.dia = x[, grep("DIA", V2)] + 2
  end.dia = x[, grep("MEDIA", V2)] - 2

  # get name of station
  estacion.detect = x[, grep("ESTACION", V9)]
  estacion.name = x[estacion.detect, V10]
  mydf = x[start.dia : end.dia, estacion := estacion.name]

  # remove empty rows and columns
  junkcol = which(colSums(is.na(mydf)) == nrow(mydf))
  junkrow = which(rowSums(is.na(mydf)) == ncol(mydf))

  if (length(junkcol) > 0) {
    mydf = mydf[, !junkcol, with = F]
  }

  if (length(junkrow) > 0) {
    mydf = mydf[!junkrow, ]
  }

  # further data cleaning

}

# bind all files
all = rbindlist(res)
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. But given that many stations have the same parameters measured for each year, I would like every time I found the "FF" indicating a new set of registers find the next number of station,  parameter name and the year, concatenate and export with that concatenated name the set of data for which you derived and extract row indices for start and end dates. And iterate inside the same txt file to find the new "FF" and do the same for the new combination of station, parameter and year that make unique and different this subset from the rest in the same txt file.

Comment: Somehow I imagine 6 different indexes that have a counter and are growing with the iteration. One index for the FF, one for the parameter name, other for the year, other for the station number and the last two for the beginning and end of the data associated, the first four indexes are used to give the name to the file, and the last two to export de proper data. What i don't know neither is if I haven't imported the table yet, is this really a row index; is there really columns and rows in the raw data? given that the fixed width is only valid for the data itself, but not for the headings.